# Dynamic LINQ OR Conditions

Tags: linq

I'm looking to use LINQ to do multiple where conditions on a collection similar to

```
IEnumerable<Object> items;
items.Where(p => p.FirstName = "John");
items.Where(p => p.LastName = "Smith");
```

except for rather than having multiple AND conditions (as with this example), I'd like to have multiple OR conditions.

**EDIT**
Sorry, to clarify I don't know how many of these conditions I will have so

```
items.Where(p => p.FirstName = "John" || p => p.LastName = "Smith")
```

won't work.

Basically, here's what I'm trying to do:

```
foreach(var name in names)
{
    items = items.Where(p => p.Name == name);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like your whitelist of names is only known at runtime. Perhaps try this:

```
string[] names = new string[] {"John", "foo", "bar"};

var matching = items.Where(x => names.Contains(x.Name));
```

Comment: It´s been super useful for me because I was already looking at Linq dynamic library just to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Use [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx):

> Suppose you want to write a LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework query that implements a keyword-style search. In other words, a query that returns rows whose description *contains* some or all of a given set of keywords...
>
> The ideal approach is to dynamically construct a lambda expression tree that performs an *or*-based predicate.
>
> Of all the things that will drive you to manually constructing expression trees, the need for dynamic predicates is the most common in a typical business application. Fortunately, it’s possible to write a set of simple and reusable extension methods that radically simplify this task. This is the role of our **PredicateBuilder** class...

Comment: Nice job, but does not work with LINQ to Entities and the Entity Framework (6): The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `.Union()` to return results that satisfy any condition.

```
var results = items.Where(p => p.FirstName == "John")
     .Union(items.Where(p => p.LastName == "Smith"));
```

This is inferior to using the `||` operator. It isn't clear from your edit why that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

```
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> OrTheseFiltersTogether<T>(
      this IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> filters)
    {
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> firstFilter = filters.FirstOrDefault();
        if (firstFilter == null)
        {
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> alwaysTrue = x => true;
            return alwaysTrue;
        }

        var body = firstFilter.Body;
        var param = firstFilter.Parameters.ToArray();
        foreach (var nextFilter in filters.Skip(1))
        {
            var nextBody = Expression.Invoke(nextFilter, param);
            body = Expression.OrElse(body, nextBody);
        }
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> result = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
        return result;
    }
```

Then, later:

```
List<Expression<Func<Person, bool>>> filters = names
  .Select<string, Expression<Func<Person, bool>>>(name => 
    p => p.Name == name
  ).ToList();

Expression<Func<Person, bool>> filterOfOrs = filters.OrTheseFiltersTogether();

query = query.Where<Person>(filterOfOrs);
```

Comment: Invoke is not supported by LINQ to Entities :(

Comment: @user288281 if that is true - sad.  Expression tree manipulation should be .net level stuff.  Having LinqToSql or LinqToEntities instances referenced by the tree should not influence your ability to create new trees from it anymore than having ints or strings.

Comment: Does anybody know how to convert this sample so it works with the entity framework. How can one avoid invoke expression? It must somehow be possible since there is the http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the `Where` clause dynamic, but you can dynamically create the Lambda Expression you pass to it. Create the right [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx), compile it and pass the resulting lambda expression  as a parameter to the Where clause.

**EDIT:**

Okay, seems like you can skip the part where you have to manually create the Expression and can use  [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) for it, as already answered by [AS-CII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391044/dynamic-linq-or-conditions/4391099#4391099).