# LINQ and OR Criteria

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, predicatebuilder

how can I programmatically create an EF query (extension methods with lambda). I understand the **and** criteria. Here is the pseudo-code:

```
var query = repository.Where(x => x.Name == "aName");

foreach(string filter in filters)
{
   query = query.Where(x => x.FilterValue.Contains(filter))
}
```

But what I want is not an and operator. I would like an or operator. How do I do this? How can I create complex criteria Trees in code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic LINQ OR Conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391044/dynamic-linq-or-conditions)

Comment: Thanks Steven. That answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

PrdicateBuilder is a nice solution. But it is complicated and not so easy to understand. See Link to other question in comment.

Also found this useful: Sometimes it is convenient to come from the other direction:

```
string[] filter = {"A", "B"};
var returnValue = repository
                .Where(x => x.Name == "aName")
                .Where(x => filter.Any(f => (x.FilterValue).Contains(f)))
                .ToList();
```