# How to perform a dynamic query with Linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am trying to perform a dynamic OR. For example:

```
test = test.Where(z => z.Id > 1);
test = test.Where(x => x.Name == "Admin"); //or name equals admin
```

I am going to pass the first query through a method then need to perform and OR instead of an and. How do I do this with Linq?

Comment: possible duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391044/dynamic-linq-or-conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) for OR effect.

```
    test1 = test.Where(z => z.Id > 1);
    test2 = test.Where(x => x.Name == "Admin"); //or name equals admin

    test = test1.Union(test2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
test = test.Where(z => z.Id > 1 || z.Name == "Admin");
```